# Migrating Java Rest Services from JDK 8 to 17

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-mail, tomcat10

Converting an Java Web Service from JDK  8 to 17.

I started to convert the javax to jakarta.  I got my project to compile.  But I get this error when I run my unit test:

```
ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void jakarta.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(javax.activation.DataHandler)'

    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.WsdlPackagingRequestFilter.initRootPart(WsdlPackagingRequestFilter.java:140)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.WsdlPackagingRequestFilter.initWsdlRequest(WsdlPackagingRequestFilter.java:99)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.WsdlPackagingRequestFilter.filterWsdlRequest(WsdlPackagingRequestFilter.java:51)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filterAbstractHttpRequest(AbstractRequestFilter.java:39)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filterRequest(AbstractRequestFilter.java:33)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.filterRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:318)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:180)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.submitRequest(WsdlSubmit.java:79)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest.submit(WsdlRequest.java:217)
    at com.stableapps.esarclientservice.COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionService.callRequest(COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionService.java:223)
    at com.stableapps.esarclientservice.COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionService.callCOREEnvelopeBatchSubmission(COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionService.java:185)
    at com.stableapps.esarclientservice.COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionService.post(COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionService.java:73)
    at com.stableapps.esarclientservice.COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionServiceTest.testPost(COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionServiceTest.java:79)
    at com.stableapps.esarclientservice.COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionServiceTest.testCompleteSubmissionCycle(COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionServiceTest.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stableapps</groupId>
    <artifactId>EsarClientService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>EsarClientService</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>smartbear-sweden-repository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.smartbear.utils.analytics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>out-app-analytics-provider</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.specs.activation-api-1.2.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1_1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                 <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Not sure what it is.  I stared to think it was some type of dependency issue between packages.

[I'm using Intellij dependency analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ATPO.png)

I looked at the other posts on stackoveflow and I tried everything their suggestions with no luck.  The method is there when I debug.  So not sure why its complaining.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Updated:
So the error is coming from this package soapui.5.4.0.  I see that it still uses javax in there:

Here are examples:

[Soap ui javax.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdNCG.png)

This is the method that it complains about.
[soap ui javax.activation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ0ij.png)

How come I don't see an updated version of soapui in maven?
[I don't see 5.7.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2HeA.png)

But I see it here?
https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/tree/release-5.7.1#prerequisites

I see that the method here uses javax.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/activation/DataHandler.html?is-external=true

Has anybody used this migration tool:
https://tomcat.apache.org/download-migration.cgi

Comment: ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError means there is no such method , this is because you may changed the version update in that updated version the method may be removed . We cannot be sure on this issue because compiled a class against a different version of the class that is missing a method, than the one you are using when running it

Comment: please check whether the other dependency has the compatibility with java 17 version before you change it

Answer (score 1):

ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError means there is no such method , this is because you may changed the version, in that updated version the method may be removed . We cannot be sure on this issue because compiled a class against a different version of the class that is missing a method, than the one you are using when running it –

Please check whether the other dependency has the compatibility with java 17 version before you change it

Comment: How do I check if a library is supported by JDK-17.  Kind of new to Java. I'm using Intellij and Eclipse.  I added a link above with the Intellij dependency analyzer I'm using.

Comment: My project is runtime is JDK-17.

Comment: @hset To see if a library supports Java 17, you read its documentation. Look especially for pages labeled *Release Notes* or *System Requirements*.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks.  I see the release notes for 5.7.1 it supports JDK 16. I see the jakarta packages used.  But some are not converted. I updated my message above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same/similar versions of `jakarta.activation` and `jakarta.mail` dependencies. I think the problem is because you use different major versions of those 2 libraries.

As an extra note, i hope its clear to you which dependencies you really need and how transient dependencies resolve. Cause i see for example that you reference `jakarta.mail` in 3 different places.

Comment: @stelios.anastaskis Thanks. I did you suggested. No luck yet. I added more notes above.